# Database table in Magento does not exist: sales_flat_shipment_grid

Tags: database, magento

We're using Magento 1.4.0.1 and want to use an extension from a 3rd party developer. The extension does not work, because of a join to the table "sales_flat_shipment_grid":

```
$collection = $model->getCollection()->join('sales/shipment_grid', 'increment_id=shipment', array('order_increment_id'=>'order_increment_id', 'shipping_name' =>'shipping_name'), null,'left');
```

Unfortunately this table does not exist n our database. So the error "Can't retrieve entity config: sales/shipment_grid" appears. If I comment this part out, the extension is working, but I guess, it does not proper work.

Does anybody know something about this table? There are a backend-option for the catalog to use the "flat table" option, but this is only for the catalog. And the tables already exists, no matter which option is checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is obvious from table name, this table contains information about shipments and is used in grid on backend. The problem is that this table was created in 1.4.1.1, so you won't find it in your store.

I see 3 ways of solving the problem:

1. You can create this table and write some script, that will fill it
   with necessary data by cron
2. You can rewrite SQL-query in that 3rd party extension so that it took necessary data from other sources
3. You can upgrade your Magento at least to 1.4.1.1 (highly recommended)

Comment: You're right. In a newer version of Magento the table exists, so your suggestions are perfect :)